# VueJS - How to separate class instances across multiple components? (With TS & decorators)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

When I use a component multiple times, a class instance is shared between them. I want to fetch async data while creating the component and then map these data into a class to work with it.

`this.product = new Product(product);` is not independent, but seems to share the same instance. All components will have the last fetched product as their product property, as if `created` would affect all components of the same name, not only the "currently rendered".

How can this be fixed?

#### Example

```
// Default setup
<script>
  import { Client } from "@app/classes/Client";
  import { Product } from "@app/classes/Product";

  export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'MyComponent' as string,
     props: {
       card: Object
     },
    data() {
      return {
        product: {}
      }
    },

    created() {
      client.fetchProduct('productname')
      .then((product) => {
        this.product = new Product(product);
      });
    }
  })
</script>

// With TS & decorators
<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
  import { Client } from "@app/classes/Client";
  import { Product } from "@app/classes/Product";

  @Component
  export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    product = {};
    created(): void {
      Client.fetchPoduct('productname')
      .then((product: {}) => {
        this.product = new Product(product);
      });
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to solve this with Vuex. I just don't get the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your case correctly, but can you clarify what's the current behaviour and what's the desired behaviour? This may depend on Client and Product which aren't shown.